# Error when trying to deploying Play framework 2.1.1 app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I got a play framework 2.1.1 java app, it runs fine on localhost.

I want to deploy it to Heroku, so I followed [these instructions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionHeroku)

Everything goes well, until I enter this line:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

When I enter this line in the CMD, I get the following error at the end:

```
remote:        [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to     /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir
/.sbt_home/plugins/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
remote:        [error] error while loading CharSequence, class file     '/tmp/scala_
buildpack_build_dir/.jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is     broken

remote:        [error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
remote:        [error] error while loading Comparator, class file     '/tmp/scala_bu
ildpack_build_dir/.jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/Comparator.class)' is broken
remote:        [error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 20)
remote:        [error] two errors found
remote:        [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
remote:        Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to run sbt!
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the     issue in
 application
remote:        code, please submit a ticket so we can help:     https://help.heroku.
com
remote:        You can also try reverting to the previous version of the     buildpa
ck by running:
remote:        $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-    buildpac
k-scala#previous-version
remote:
remote:        Thanks,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git'
```

I really have no idea what to do, anyone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your trying to deploy an app that uses Scala 2.9, which does not support Java 8. But Java 8 is the default on Heroku.

Try adding a system.properties file to the root directory of your app, and put the following code in it:

```
java.runtime.version=1.7
```

Then add the file to your Git repo and redeploy like so:

```
$ git add system.properties
$ git commit -m "Set JDK version to 7"
$ git push heroku master
```